# Написать функцию зависимости количества удвоенных множителей от количества слагаемых

Tags: c++, математика

Имеем сумму квадратов `(а+b)²`. Количество удвоенных множителей равно `1(2ab)`. При увеличении количества слагаемых, например, при `(a+b+c)²` количество удвоенных множителей равно `3(2ab+2ac+2bc)`.
Задача в том, чтобы написать функцию, где **m** - количество слагаемых в скобках `(a+b+...)²`, **n** - количество удвоенных множителей `(2ab+2bc...)`. `m` - входная величина, `n` - выходная. Застрял тупо на поиске зависимости))

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), то есть ваши попытки реализации.

Comment: (а+b)² - это квадрат суммы, а не сумма квадратов.

Comment: Ну подумайте сами - первый сомножитель в паре выбирается m способами, второй - (m-1) - из оставшихся. Итого их m(m-1) - но так как ab == ba, то надо поделить общее число пополам. n = m(m-1)/2...

Answer (score 1):

Число сочетаний из *n* по *k* определяется [биномиальным коэффициентом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В вашем случае k равно 2, n равно количеству слагаемых.

Answer (score 1):

@Эникейщик, или проще:

```
int m; 
std::cin >> m; // любое число.
int n = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < m; ++i){
    n += i;
}
std::cout << n; // ответ.
```

**update**
Проверил с формулой от @Эникейщик, все сошлось для 3, 5, 10. Дальше не стал проверять.

Comment: Дожились... считаем сумму 1+2+3+...+m с помощью цикла... В каком классе учат арифметические прогрессии?

Answer (score 0):

cout << m * (m - 1) / 2;